# WebClient DownloadFile downloads corrupt jpeg for redirected URI's

Tags: .net, file, download, webclient

I am having some issues downloading jpeg images using the WebClient class.  I am trying to download jpeg images via the following code:

```
public bool DownloadUri(string strUri, string destPath)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(strUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(uri, destPath);
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The majority work fine although when a jpeg doesn't exist, the site from which I am trying to download redirects and the download doesn't throw an exception, it downloads a corrupt jpeg of only 8k in size.  Here is one of the offending urls that I've been provided:

http://axisproperty.net.au/Upload/listing/500748870/500748870_1_500266205%2c1336368187%2cImageA.jpg

I already validate that the uri using a Uri.TryCreate and a Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(urlAttribute.Value, UriKind.Absolute).  I've tried to do a File.Exists(uri.ToString()) to verify that the uri has a valid file associated to it although this fails even for valid url's.

Is there any other way to validate that the file actually exists so I don't download all these unnecessary corrupt jpeg files?

Answer (score 0):

http redirects are not handled by webclient.downloadfile method

you should use webrequest for that

```
public static int DownloadFile(String remoteFilename, String localFilename)
    {
      // Function will return the number of bytes processed
      // to the caller. Initialize to 0 here.
      int bytesProcessed = 0;

      // Assign values to these objects here so that they can
      // be referenced in the finally block
      Stream remoteStream = null;
      Stream localStream = null;
      WebResponse response = null;

      // Use a try/catch/finally block as both the WebRequest and Stream
      // classes throw exceptions upon error
      try
      {
        // Create a request for the specified remote file name
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(remoteFilename);
        if (request != null)
        {
          // Send the request to the server and retrieve the
          // WebResponse object 
          response = request.GetResponse();
          if (response != null)
          {
            // Once the WebResponse object has been retrieved,
            // get the stream object associated with the response's data
            remoteStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Create the local file
            localStream = File.Create(localFilename);

            // Allocate a 1k buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            // Simple do/while loop to read from stream until
            // no bytes are returned
            do
            {
              // Read data (up to 1k) from the stream
              bytesRead = remoteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

              // Write the data to the local file
              localStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

              // Increment total bytes processed
              bytesProcessed += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
        // Close the response and streams objects here 
        // to make sure they're closed even if an exception
        // is thrown at some point
        if (response != null) response.Close();
        if (remoteStream != null) remoteStream.Close();
        if (localStream != null) localStream.Close();
      }

      // Return total bytes processed to caller.
      return bytesProcessed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I should of been more clear.  The url that I've been provided is invalid and therefore redirects to a page not found page or similar so in that case I don't want to download as there is no valid jpeg image in that file.  I found the following solution:

```
public static bool CheckURL(string URL)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
        using (HttpWebResponse rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            if ((rsp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && rsp.ContentType.ToLower() == "image/jpeg")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```